# Can the mass of a rocky Super Giant be artificially reduced?

Tags: science-based, planets, science-fiction, rocky-planets

**THE PREMISE:**

Let's imagine a solar system with at least **two rocky planets**.
One is **Earth sized *"A"*** (or smaller) and the second is a **Super Giant *"B"***.

Both are in the habitable zone of their sun. *A* is closer to the sun.

On planet *A*, life develops.
The mass of *B* attracts most celestial bodies and avoid them to crash on *A*.

As time passes by the mass of *B* is getting greater and greater.
Either it's starting to capture more gas (and might become an unstable Gas Giant) , or either its mass starts to have an impact on *A*'s orbit.

In any case, the people living on *A*, a very developed intelligence, fear of a gravitational kick out of the system due to *B*'s mass/change of orbit (if it becomes unstable due to the gas, I'm not sure what might be the best explanation yet).

Therefore the people of Planet *A* decide to do something before their planet gets kicked and life destroyed. As Planet *B* is still important for their survival (since it attracts celestial bodies), and they can't just leave their planet and find "a new one", they go to planet *B*, with the intention to reduce its mass.

**THE QUESTION**:

**Given that a civilization has the technology and means to do so (unobtainium is okay in that scenario), can the mass of a Super Giant be reduced and how so ?**

The idea is to have the people of *A* on planet *B*, for a long time, doing some sort of "terra forming" but in order to stop the increase of *B*'s mass. Can they add more water ? Hollow the planet ? Change its core ?

Note that it is also important that life ends up developing on planet *B* and the people of *A* do not want to kill life on planet *B* but still be able to reduce the mass of the planet at the same time.
(I also hope I am not mistaking "mass" with "density")

Comment: "can the mass of a Super Giant be reduced" and "the people of A do not want to destroy it as they reduce the mass of the planet". are contradictory statement. Please clarify.

Comment: I made an edit! I was talking about life on the planet, not the planet itself. Sorry for the confusion I hope it's clearer

Comment: everything you do to significantly change the planet will seriously endanger any native life. you can't just reduce the mass of a planet and hope the animals and plants won't care. for one thing, reduced gravity means the atmosphere will get thinner.

Comment: @ths I agree with that statement. Note that I added that life must develop **eventually**. From that I meant that maybe reducing the mass of the planet could cause a massive extinction of the life on the planet as it was (early signs of life) but life could grow once again? just like Earth went through massive extinctions itself. The people of planet A care about life on planet B but their survival is their priority. If their action caused a mass extinction, they could try to rebuild life with the new parameters of the mass reduced planet. Would that be possible with the thinner atmosphere?

Comment: What is "gaz", please? A misspelling of "gas" or some other substance?

Comment: A misspelling of "gas". Gas is spelled "gaz" in my language. So this is just a typo as I translated.

Comment: Why would gas make a planet unstable? What even *is* an "unstable" planet?

Comment: Giant gas planets can change their orbit either at the very beginning of their life or at their end. Becoming "unstable" means that their disk of gas pile up then dissipate. Their orbits can change and then meet the orbit of another planet. That's when smaller, rocky planets can get gravitationally kicked out of the system (or into their star). You can find more here: https://planetplanet.net/2019/02/06/how-planets-die-when-good-jupiters-go-bad/

Comment: Gas planets don't generally have "disks of gas", atmospheres don't just suddenly dissipate, and changes in orbit are almost entirely due to interactions with other planets. You've got cause and effect all mixed up and are confusing events that happen while a planetary system is forming with events that happen long afterward.

Comment: I'm not saying that I might not be wrong so here's my trian of thought: 1) "When a planet reaches a few times the mass of Earth, the atmosphere will grow rapidly, faster than the solid part of the planet, eventually forming a gas giant planet like Jupiter" 2) there are other giant gas planets in the system after planet B, and can give it nudges once its mass gets greater. 3)Systems often go unstable on their own, tiny changes in the planets’ orbits accumulate until they reach a point of no return. 4) the gravitational pull itself could be a menace enough to the planets nearby.

Comment: If there is any mistake in the way I imagined this, please point them out to me.

Comment: The bit quoted in 1 is about something that happens *early in planet formation*, not billions of years later when the solar system has been cleared of almost all gas and debris and some civilization is considering planetary engineering projects. And yes, planetary orbits may remain stable for long periods of time and then experience changes, but it's quite unlikely for that to coincide with a civilization existing in the system.

Answer (score 3):

The people on planet A don't really have any chance of reducing the size of planet B. The only way to do so would be to ship mass off of the planet and it simply would not be practical to ship enough material off planet. There efforts would be confounded by the continuous infall of material from space, the sheer bulk of an astronomical body like a planet and their grossly limited capabilities.

To make an impossible situation even worse, planet B is a super-giant so the sheer quantity of material that would need removing is even bigger. To cap it all due to the rocket equation and the size of planet Earth, it is extremely difficult to reach Earth orbit as it is. Depending on the exact parameters of the super-giant it is likely that it would not even be possible (or remotely practical) to leave its surface using chemical rockets.

Your only hope is some form of unobtainium "magic", but in that circumstance almost anything is possible.

Comment: For the technology, I do not mind unobtainium to explain that the people from planet A have the means to make the journey from A to B several times without much difficulty.
B needs to be a super giant to explain that: 1) it might gravitationally kick planet A from their orbit and the system 
2) it protects planet A from celestial bodies (it's a ringed planet).
I do not know what are the exact size parameters, but if B can be smaller to make everything above + the mass reducing possible, I wouldn't mind. I mainly wonder what might be the most plausible way to reduce mass other than mining.

Comment: I think you will have your work cut out to make this believable to the more scientifically literate. Mining will not reduce the mass of the planet unless what is mined is moved off of the planet. Getting most of the planet effectively "off of the planet" is not really a practical proposition in all honesty.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured. I think I'll go for unobtianium unfortunately since the presence of people A on planet B is a crucial point story wise. I think I'll have to go with handwaving alien technology capable to make viable space elevators. Unobtianium will definitely be the material for the tethers towards geostationary stations where most of the mass would be brought and then sent away from the planet B's orbit. I know space elevators aren't feasible with our current materials, technology and Earth's parameters but I think this will have to do

Comment: OK, but what happens to the planetary material when its in orbit? It will need to be sent away somewhere, I wouldn't underestimate the volume requirements it wouldn't be anything like mining as we know it. At a million cubic km a day it would be a slow process.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to use the material to build anything that would be useful to planet A's people. Either be fuel, spaceships, geostationary stations, and release everything unuseful in outer space. However I agree that this process would take a lot, lot of time. In the story it's actually a good thing as the people of planet A are supposed to stay a very long time on this planet, but I'm aware that this might be impossible unless I just say that they have "the technology to do so".

Comment: I think the real issue is scale and getting your head around the orders of magnitude thing. Total steel production on Earth is much less than 1 cubic kilometre per year. And that's a lot of stuff to be needing. What are they going to do with a million cubic km? Every day?

Answer (score 1):

**Mining**

The only way to make it smaller is to mine the hell out of it.

Planet A sends self replicating robots to mine the planet and build space stations, Dyson satellites, ring worlds, ark ships, whatever.

[image]

This mass is gone from the planet and used to make useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks, mining was my n°1 solution. But I was also wondering if that might result in a potential collapse of the crust ? I guess there should be "pillars" strong enough inside the mines to avoid such thing ?

Comment: Mind that the satellites have to be orbiting something else than the planet they are mined from in order to reduce its mass

Comment: @L.Dutch I did say Dyson Satellites which would orbit the sun capturing sunlight and transferring the energy for use elsewhere.

Comment: @Delkhii Why would you mine underground? Surface mining would be enough. Even gas mining would change the mass.

Comment: @Thorne
wouldn't mining the surface put life at risk on the planet B ?

Comment: @L.Dutch I agree, everything that would be build would be used for planet A instead of letting it stay around B orbit.

Comment: @Delkhii Why, does mining now put life at risk on Earth? It's a hole in the ground. Life can move to the side.

Comment: To me the people of planet A would have been heavily mining the planet all over the surface, as they do not have much time and to keep it even in depth. I thought such project would be like some heavy terraforming and could destroy entire biomes.
However as they do care about life they could do something to save life by only doing some parts at a time I guess.

Comment: Mine are already rehabilitated here. You mine a section and restore the biome when you finish and move to the new area. Life regrows where it was once cleared.

Comment: "I agree, everything that would be build would be used for planet A": you're talking about enough material to substantially reduce the mass of planet B. Realistically, this is probably more mass than the entire planet A. Is that *really* what you want to do with that material?

Comment: What I meant by that was not to pile up the material on planet A but for it to be used to **build**. Spaceships, fuel, geostationary stations, anything in space. Planet A's people are definitely advanced enough to go from one planet to another, their technology doesn't really have any limit nor is very relevant to my story. But the main idea was for them to use the mined materials and reused them to build, and whatever junk left would be probably released into outer space.

Comment: @Delkhii the point is, that mass doesn't go away because you made something else out of it. The moon produces larger tides than the sun. An Earth mass in geostationary orbit, at a tenth the distance, would cause catastrophic disruptions. Even if it were carefully distributed into a uniform ring, it would have drastic effects on satellite orbits and would be a potential future threat to the planet if they became unable to maintain it for some reason. You are talking about something on the scale of dismantling and rebuilding planets, and don't seem to recognize this.

Comment: I do. My main question was more about how it can be done, and less what to do with the mass once taken away. For this I might go for the unobtianium road. I sure would love for it to have an easy and feasible solution, but as you said, it's still mining a planet and the consequences are enormous. Their greed to have monumental stations around their planet and create disruptions in the world they wanted to save would be an interesting possibility, even tho that would mean people of planet A are not thinking long term which is contradictory. This or having most stations being non geostationary.

Comment: Any mass doesn't need to orbit the planet. You'd build habitats and place them much further out

Comment: I agree. Most of it can be out of the planet A's orbit. It would be counter productive to bring all the mass from B to A. A few stations, whatever they feel they can use material for, and everything in outer space. Maybe an artifical planet further away in case things go sour? Since their technology don't have much limit, anything is kinda possible for what they do with what they mined out of planet B.